# Is my router not capable for WAN security

Tags: router, firmware

I am using Dlink Dir 600 L. 
Current Firmware Version :2.04
Current Firmware Date : Tue 15 Oct 2013

I checked Dlink's website and found no new firmware. I also tried DD-WRT and   openwrt but cant install them. When I try to upload the firmwares it always end up in and error message.

So my question is if I continue using the default (Dlink) firmware is it a security issue ? I am not asking about wireless security I am talking about WAN security.

Comment: don't they have support to call and check ?

Comment: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-899/product_id-31624/version_id-182671/D-link-Dir-600l-Firmware-2.05.html

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie in security..... What does that security report mean ? I see score 10 highlighted in red. What does that mean ?

Comment: @linuxyogi 10 is the "worst" score you can get, in that it has a very serious vulnerability that is easy to exploit that would allow remote code execution on your device if exploited. The short answer to your question is no, it is not secure.

Comment: @ DKNUCKLES I use only Linux. No Windows machine here. My ISP provides connection using ethernet cable. So my question is if I plug in the ethernet cable directly to my PC's NIC will it be better in terms of security ?

Comment: @linuxyogi is you "PC" a router ?

Comment: @adam86  No it has only one NIC running Ubuntu. Right now there is no connection sharing but its better to run it this way rather than using a router with that kind of security flaw.